# "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL" when downloading canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, download, html5-canvas

In my website, I am trying to download tainted canvases that I have created. I get the "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL:" (followed with a string of data) when I try to do this.

I have looked at other posts about this and they are generally trying to show their canvas or something else instead of saving the canvas.

Here is my code:

```
//it looks complicated, but the only important lines are the ones before the else statement,
function download_img(el) {
//the if statement is used to see if this is using the canvas or not
    if(document.getElementById("canvasImage").style.display != "none"){
        alert('canvas')
        var canvImg = document.getElementById("canvasImage").toDataURL("image/jpg");
        el.href = canvImg;        
    }else{
//again, this code is for the image side of the project, which works fine
        alert('image')
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", document.getElementById("theImg").src, true);
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function(){
            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
            var tag = document.createElement('a');
            tag.href = imageUrl;
            tag.download = "meme";
            document.body.appendChild(tag);
            tag.click();
            document.body.removeChild(tag);
        }
        xhr.send();       
    }
}
```

My HTML:

```
    <a style="float:left;display:inline;" href="" onclick="download_img(this)">Canvas Button</a>
```

What I want to happen is that the canvas is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `download` attribute to the `<a>` tag to force it to download instead of navigate.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. For reference to anyone who is confused, write in the <a> tag 'download= fooName'